# How did Fabius and Lucius survive the assault on the Iron Hand's ship?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

In the book *Angel Exterminatus* from the *Horus Heresy*, Perturabo and Fulgrim launch an assault on one "rogue" Iron Hand's ship.

During this assault, Lucius faces a lone Raven Guard saved from Istvann V by the Iron Hands. This Raven Guard is an extremely dangerous opponent, as Lucius, a great (if not the best of the Emperor's Children) swordsman, says himself.

We do not know how the fight ends, but later on, the Raven Guard (I forgot his name, something like Shadowkyn) helps defend the (nearly) dead captain of the ship against Fabius, who is stabbed at least twice in the torso.

Considering that it is not said that this happened before the fight with Lucius and that it is written after the text of the fight with Lucius, I deduce that the Raven Guard won against Lucius (and most likely killed him.)

Moreover, it is not written that Fabius leaves the Iron Hand's ship.

Later, the Iron Hand's ship leaves the battle field (in an unconventional way) and yet, Lucius and Fabius are mentioned as being "well" (at least alive.)

How did Lucius and Fabius leave the Iron Hand's ship? Why did the Raven Guard not kill Lucius and Fabius?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Lucius

Sharrowkyn killed Lucius, as described in the book. From the book, chapter 26

> Sharrowkyn’s blades stabbed down behind Lucius’s collarbone, tearing through his hearts and lungs, severing arteries and wreaking catastrophic damage that not even a Space Marine’s post-human physiology could undo. And all thoughts of a worthy valediction died with him.

Which is later also confirmed by Fabius, who asks him how he survived. Book, Chapter 27, at the end:

> Fabius waved away his question. ‘Nothing of any concern to the likes of you, swordsman. I could ask you the same thing. When the Phoenician brought you to me you were cold and dead. How is it that you live?’ Lucius shook his head. ‘I don’t know. Death doesn’t want me yet.’

So, Lucius was dead and returned to life without him understanding. He later gets the blessing from Slaanesh to revive if the oponent killing him even feels the slightest pleasure / satisfaction:

> Lucius died, and his death was an experience of such transcendent pleasure that Slaanesh himself took notice: he could not let such a promising marine slip away. In the following days, Cyrius began to change: lines began to appear over his skin and his hair started to fall out. Lucius was back in the world of the living, and all that remained of Cyrius was a screaming face in the warped artificer armour. This has happened many times since then: whenever his killer takes even the tiniest moment of enthusiasm, pleasure, or satisfaction from besting Lucius, they will begin to change into him and become just another swirling face, a memory in the armor in which Lucius is clad.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on Lucius The Eternal](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Lucius_the_Eternal)

We don't know for certain but the death by Sharrowkyn might be the doing of Slaanesh in reviving him for the first time. But as Lexicanum describes it, Sharrowkyn took no pleasure in it and therefore Slaanesh had to simply revive him and not take over Sharrowkyn, as described in the Lucius article:

> Lucius's codex entries consistently describe his first death coming at the hands of Lord Commander Cyrius. Angel Exterminatus has Lucius die at the hands of Nykona Sharrowkin and reawaken in Fabius's apothecarion. However, this death was specifically said to never give Sharrowkyn any satisfaction, which may mean that his death at Cyrius' hands was merely the first to meet the conditions for his resurrection by Slaanesh.
>
> From the same article as above.

## Fabius

From the Book, chapter 16:

> ‘Brother Sharrowkyn,’said Tarsa. ‘Is there something wrong with the floor?’Fabius turned to see the Raven Guard drop from the tangle of cables and pipework on the ceiling. Two black-bladed swords plunged into Fabius’s chest, and oily black gore squirted from the wounds. The Apothecary fell back, his rictus features twisted in open-mouthed horror. Sharrowkyn wrenched the swords out and pivoted on his heel to hurl one of his blades. It spun in the air and punched through the helm of one of the Emperor’s Children, who dropped with a strangled shriek of dissonant sound that echoed painfully in Tarsa’s skull. Before Sharrowkyn could finish Fabius, the last of the monsters threw itself at him.

Bombastus, a Dreadnought of the Iron Hands, then comes into the Apothecarion and kills the monster. However, everybody is focused on the fight of the Dreadnought versus the abomination, leading to:

> Tarsa looked around for the Emperor’s Children who had come so close to killing him and disrupting Captain Branthan’s stasis casket. They had fled at the sight of Bombastus, and Tarsa couldn’t say he blamed them.

So, Sharrowkyn was able to injure Fabius but not enough to endanger his life, specially with the Astartes physiology. The interruption of the Space Marine abomination gave him enough time to flee.

Comment: Dammit ! I think you sploiled me. I stopped my reading session before those chapters. (No problem though, I asked for it :p).
I'll will gladly read more in detail your answer and give you the part where Sharrowkyn fights Fabius tonight.

Comment: @Itération122442 Chewing more than you can swallow ;)

Comment: Chapter 16. When the salamander gets beaten by Fabius and his men (defending the nearly dead captain), the Salamander (Atesh Tarsa) says, in response to Fabius who asks why he is smiling: "Brother Sharrowkyn, is there a problem whith the ground?". Right after the Raven Guard gets down from the roof and stabs Fabius. (This is my translation, my version of the book not being in english)

Comment: @Itération122442 There you go.